# Synchronisation failed, dropping peer; err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"; message loop

Tags: synchronization, clique

I have clique private proof-of-authority chain.

I have updated all signer nodes' (currently I have 3 signer nodes) geth version to minimum `Version: 1.8.16-stable`. Also I have updated the other node that gives the error to `v1.8.16`.

[image]

The way I run my `geth` also tried without `--syncmode fast` flag.

`geth --syncmode fast --cache=1024 --shh --datadir $DATADIR/private  --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain="*" --networkid 12345 --rpcapi admin,eth,net,web3,debug,personal,shh`

---

Error I am having on multiple nodes that are connected into the network.

```
########## BAD BLOCK #########
Chain config: {ChainID: 23422 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: clique}

Number: 1260001
Hash: 0x659e96f35e1fa1c39fc3b8370a336f78787e482aef44e56bbe6dd9e10bb06bdc


Error: recently signed
##############################

WARN [10-05|15:49:57.694] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=ae57fcb24c19102e err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
INFO [10-05|15:49:57.694] message loop                             peer=ae57fcb24c19102e err=EOF
ERROR[10-05|15:50:07.707]
########## BAD BLOCK #########
Chain config: {ChainID: 23422 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: clique}

Number: 1260001
Hash: 0x659e96f35e1fa1c39fc3b8370a336f78787e482aef44e56bbe6dd9e10bb06bdc
```

---

- I have reverted back the blockchain into some previous block number, `debug.setHead("0x124F80")` (1200000 th block) but it did not help.
- Please note that I have to remove my chaindata `geth removedb` and sync from the start, which also didn't help.

---

**Possible Solution:**

- Should I take back the signer nodes' blockchain data to point where error does not occurred using `debug.setHead()`? This could be a short-term solution where the same error could be occurred again.

---

**=>** Opened [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17849#issuecomment-427297989).

Comment: Is it only one node having this error? Did you try to delete the database files from datadir, reinit datadir with the genesis file (``geth init``), then resync without ``--syncmode fast``?

Comment: Not a single node, all the nodes that connects to the network and start syncing from genesis block. But I have three signer nodes, which continues to increase the block size. I will try without `--syncmode fast` and let you know.

Comment: You have a mix of stable and unstable geth versions. Did you try 1.8.16-stable instead of 1.8.17-unstable for the nodes with the error?

Comment: Both gives the same error, doesn't matter which one. Geth developers told me that its an issue related to geth version v1.8.14 and v1.8.15. (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/17620). But updating the geth version doesn't do any help.

Comment: I have re-synced from the genesis block without `--syncmode fast` flag and face with the same error. Here is the network status of my private network: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/3a5233ae05493db002f57a3c708e117b, you can see more than one node stuck at blockNumber=1,260,000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the signers does not recognize some past block became invalid.

As a solution, first I have updated `geth` version of signer nodes to equal or above to `v1.8.16`. Later, I have rewind the chain back to the faulty snapshot block (epoch transition) for all the signer nodes using `debug.setHead("0x124F80")` (1200000th block).
[Site](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter) to convert decimal value to hexadecimal value, don't forget to add `0x` ad the beginning.

---

From `@karalabe`'s answer on the opened [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17849#issuecomment-428254931):

> There was a bug in one Geth release (v1.8.14/v1.8.15) that violated
> the Clique consensus spec, causing some signers to create blocks when
> they weren't allowed to (epoch transition). All previous and
> subsequent version of Geth (apart from the faulty one) correctly
> rejected those blocks, hence why you couldn't sync a new node to your
> already mined chain.
>
> A node however does not re-validate blocks when you update it, so even
> though you updated your signers, they were oblivious to the fact that
> a faulty block was already in their chain. When you rewound the chain,
> the signers had to re-mine the faulty segment, correcting the issue.
>
> This should most definitely not happen again, as long as you don't use
> the faulty version of Geth. Any version equal or above to v1.8.16
> should work just fine.