# Can a Parity node can connect into Clique Proof-of-Authority consensus engine?

Tags: parity, clique

I have setup private  Proof-of-Authority consensus engine (also named `clique`) network with `Geth`.

- Can a `Parity` node connect into it? If yes, how?

[Parity-goerli](https://github.com/goerli/parity-goerli) does this for AuRa (Parity's Proof-of-Authority (PoA) consensus engine), where also a `geth` node could connect into it. But I am not sure that could it also be done for clique network as well.

Comment: There is a feature request for this in GitHub: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/5687 - however, it looks like there is no focus on it anymore, but rather on https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/7162 (EIP-1011: Hybrid Casper FFG / Ethash) (?)

Comment: `Geth-clique` is pretty solid but I do face with `retrieved hash chain is invalid` error please see ( https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60023/synchronisation-failed-dropping-peer-err-retrieved-hash-chain-is-invalid-me ); where all peers stuck at exact same block number. This error forces me to switch into alternative like `Parity`. Since I cannot make hybrid connection, my only option left to completely switch into `Parity-aura`.

Comment: I am using geth clique for a private chain setup for a year now. Works perfectly fine so far. I‘ll look at your question.

Comment: Same, I am using `geth-clique` setup for a year without a problem till yesterday. I assume the problem I am facing is a solvable one.