# Synchronisation failed, dropping peer peer=... err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: block in the future" in private geth ethereum network

Tags: synchronization, nodes, enode

**Geth Version:** 1.10.7-stable-12f0ff40

**Operating system:** Windows 10 Home

I have created a Private Ethereum Blockchain with 2 nodes in seperated command prompts:

```
geth --http --http.port "8085" --datadir C:/Users/rapado/AppData/Local/Ethereum/PrivateChain init C:/Users/rapado/AppData/Local/Ethereum/genesis.json
geth --http --http.port "8085" --datadir C:/Users/rapado/AppData/Local/Ethereum/PrivateChain2 init C:/Users/rapado/AppData/Local/Ethereum/genesis.json
```

Then I started my Blockchain nodes in 2 seperated command prompts:

```
geth --http --http.api debug,admin,miner,personal,eth,net,web3 --http.port "8085" --datadir C:/Users/rapado/AppData/Local/Ethereum/PrivateChain --networkid 989 --nodiscover --syncmode "full"
geth --http --http.api debug,admin,miner,personal,eth,net,web3 --http.port "8086" --datadir C:/Users/rapado/AppData/Local/Ethereum/PrivateChain2 --networkid 989 --nodiscover --port 30306 --ipcdisable --syncmode "full"
```

I have created one account per node. After that I added the second node to the first node as a static node via the static-nodes.json:

```
[
"enode://e561e03dcf01cc719905b916f5a9e1453e99e8acd2125d2e097940c3e34a6e416f507cc5d476e258a601be1acd1d84f45a6623d5e3fb5945a268ee7ebc20b758@127.0.0.1:30306?discport=0"
]
```

Afterwards, I did miner.start() in node one in javascript console, which I opened with

```
geth attach http://localhost:8085
```

In console, I get the warn that the synchronisation failed, because the block is in the future:

```
INFO [08-23|10:22:13.231] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 
elapsed=0s        mgasps=NaN   number=215 hash=a330db..1a62a8 dirty=5.48KiB
INFO [08-23|10:22:13.261] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=8.120ms   mgasps=0.000 number=216 hash=b49e59..1399ec dirty=5.72KiB
INFO [08-23|10:22:13.275] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=0s        mgasps=NaN   number=217 hash=b08d0f..f7c365 dirty=5.96KiB
INFO [08-23|10:22:13.407] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=5.220ms   mgasps=0.000 number=218 hash=3f4dc5..0ce908 dirty=6.20KiB
WARN [08-23|10:22:14.446] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=dc15b118e270aba9e1ec49ef6fab236d12eadf3229e1cb9af4c45f7406ff699e err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: block in the future"
INFO [08-23|10:22:14.607] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=0 static=0
INFO [08-23|10:22:18.100] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=6.3ms     mgasps=0.000 number=220 hash=e087e5..1861bc dirty=6.67KiB
WARN [08-23|10:22:24.614] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=dc15b118e270aba9e1ec49ef6fab236d12eadf3229e1cb9af4c45f7406ff699e err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: block in the future"
INFO [08-23|10:22:27.808] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=0 static=0
INFO [08-23|10:22:28.103] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=2.687ms   mgasps=0.000 number=230 hash=068406..a394e0 dirty=9.05KiB
INFO [08-23|10:22:58.153] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
WARN [08-23|10:22:58.167] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=dc15b118e270aba9e1ec49ef6fab236d12eadf3229e1cb9af4c45f7406ff699e err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: block in the future"
INFO [08-23|10:23:03.108] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=4.077ms   mgasps=0.000 number=264 hash=fa1970..2fb3a3 dirty=17.16KiB
INFO [08-23|10:23:33.167] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
INFO [08-23|10:23:33.169] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=582.00B throttle=8192
INFO [08-23|10:23:33.179] Imported new chain segment               blocks=13 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=5.846ms   mgasps=0.000 number=277 hash=7edbca..97641b dirty=20.25KiB
```

As described in [another thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60023/synchronisation-failed-dropping-peer-err-retrieved-hash-chain-is-invalid-me) I tried to do geth.removedb and debug.setHead("..."). Also, I tried to reinstall Geth and recreate the network/nodes.

Unfortunately, none of this helped solve the sync error.

I hope someone can help me and already a big thank you! :)

Comment: That is strange error for two nodes running in the same computer, try increasing the verbosity log level to check if there's something else wrong.