# How to handle Ropsten's chain split with geth 1.10.8

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I upgraded and restarted geth connected to Ropsten to 1.10.8, but the content is different from Ethrscan and infura.io from 10920274 block.
And my geth has the latest block number of about 7,000 blocks larger.
Do I need to do anything other than upgrade and reboot?

Comment: If the node has diverged it won't synchronize, you have to reset the chain to a block before the fork. In geth use debug.setHead from the console with the block number in hexadecimal. See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/60240 for a use of debug.setHead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.　I also tried debug.setHead and full block sync but it didn't solve the problem.　My geth still sees longer chains than ethscan and infra.io.

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/ethereum/pm/issues/354#issuecomment-885687324, for instructions given in the previous ropsten fork for 1.10.6. If you have synchronized from zero using the latest version perhaps you are on the right fork and Etherscan is in the wrong one.

Comment: Many times Thank you.　github.com/ethereum/pm/issues/354#issuecomment-885687324 was very helpful.　If I know the correct chain contents, the whitelist function seems to solve the problem.　But I can't tell which chain is right...